# Higher Adeles of a scheme and related topics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, simplicial-stuff, local-fields, adeles

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme. I will describe a construction of a simplicial ring which I think is called the Bellinson higher Adeles complex (or something similar).

Consider the augmented simplicial set of chains of points in $X$ denoted by $S(X)$. It is defined as follows:

- The $-1$-simplices a one point set: $S(X)_{-1}=\{1\}$ and the augmentation $d_{-1}: S(X)_0 \to S(X)_{-1}$ is just the only possible map.
- An $n\ge0$ -simplex $\xi \in S(X)_{n}$ is a chain of points $\xi = \{x_0,...,x_n\}$ s.t.  $x_{i+1} \in \overline{\{x_{i}\}}$.
- The face maps remove a point in the chain and the degeneracy repeat a point. Explicitly $d_{i}(\xi)=\{x_0,...,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},...,x_n\}$, $s_i(\xi) = \{x_0,...,x_{i-1},x_{i},x_{i},x_{i+1},...,x_n\}$.

We now define localization of a coherent sheaf $M$ w.r.t. to a chain $\xi$. The definition is inductive:

- If $\xi = {1}$ we define $M_{\xi}=\Gamma(X,M)$.
- For a chain $\xi \in S(X)_n$ we define $M_{\xi}:= \lim_{j \to \infty} (M_{x_n}/\mathfrak{m}_{x_n}^{j+1} M_{x_n})_{d_n\xi}$

This is functorial (and exact) so when fixing $M=\mathcal{O}_X$ the above localizations fit into a simplicial commutative ring with the face and degeneracies induced from the corresponding maps on chains. Call this simplicial commutative ring $\mathbb{A}_{\bullet}(\mathcal{O}_X)$. The same can be done for any coherent sheaf $M$ to obtain a simplicial module $\mathbb{A}_\bullet(M)$ over the simplicial ring $\mathbb{A}_{\bullet}(\mathcal{O}_X)$.

**We get a "localization" functor $\mathbb{A}_\bullet(-): Coh(X) \to \mathbb{A}_\bullet(\mathcal{O}_X)-Mod$.**

I think if everything is characteristic $0$ there's no problem in extending this functor via an equivalence so that the target will be $DG$-modules over the $DG$-algebra correpsponding to $\mathbb{A}_\bullet(\mathcal{O}_X)$.

> **First question:** **Is this functor $\mathbb{A}_\bullet(-)$ full? faithful?** If not can we modify the target category by remembering the topology of the various completions so that it is? **Can we modify so that this becomes an equivalence?** Basically: **Can we reconstruct a noetherian scheme from its complex/simplicial ring of higher adeles?**

I found this construction when trying to read about and understand residue complexes, injective hulls, dualizing complexes, differential operators and their various connections. Alas what I found so far was too technical for me to understand or even extract the big picture.

> **Second question:** **What is the big picture** here regarding the construction of the **residue complex** from these adeles? How does it interact with **differential operators/injective hulls/dualizing complexes?** Is their a **friendly source that discusses these topics**? (By friendly I mean in particular that I prefer it having no proofs at all then being too technical to digest).

Comment: Could you please tell where to read about this stuff? How is it related to "ordinary" adeles?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I got this from papers by yekutieli e.g. https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~amyekut/publications/bcas/journal.pdf. There are others, look up "explicit residue complex" or bellinson completion algebras and you'll find them. As I said they were too dense and technical for me to grasp. I think that in the case of a smooth curve you get a complex which at one degree has the function field and at the other precisely the classical adeles.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Correction: To get the adeles (meaning the restricted product and not just the arbitrary product) you should modify this probably. Perhaps some kind of limit over all finite sub-simplicial sets of $S(X)$. I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks! In the meanwhile I found a very accurate [paper](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02950770.pdf) by Annette Huber, she explicitly states that for the $\mathcal O$ sheaf over the spectrum of a Dedekind ring you get exactly the classical adeles.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე If you could comment about how she does things differently so that it does work it would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry this is completely new (and exciting!) stuff for me, I certainly need some time to learn it.